# Successive Mean Sums of Random Variables

Tags: summation, random-variables

How we can prove  the following: $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are $i.i.d$ random variables having all the moments of order less than 4, so 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i X_j X_k X_l] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i^4] + 3 n(n-1) \big(\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]\big)^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: thank you Davide Giraudo for your solution, But the coefficient is not equal to 3.

Comment: Which coefficient do you mean?

Comment: The coefficient $\binom 42$ is equal to 6 not 3. Can you explain more please. Than you so much Davide Giraudo.

Comment: I agree that $\binom 42=6$, but the sum I wrote is $\frac{n(n-1)}2, which is what is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to assume that $\mathbb EX_0=0$, otherwise the formula doesn't hold true (tale $X_i=1$). Let $S:=\{(i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4)\in [n]\}$. If $\mathbf i=(i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4)\in S$, denote by $S_k:=\{\mathbb i\in S, \mbox{ the maximum of the }i_j \mbox{'s is reached }k\mbox{ times}\}$.

Then 
$$\sum_{\mathbf i\in S}\mathbb E(X_{i_1}X_{i_2}X_{i_3}X_{i_4})=\sum_{\mathbf i\in S_1}+\sum_{\mathbf i\in S_2}+\sum_{\mathbf i\in S_3}+\sum_{\mathbf i\in S_4}.$$
The first sum of the RHS vanishes by independence and because the random variables are zero-mean. The same argument shows that the third sum vanishes.

The second one is subdivided into two ones: the non-maximals indexes are the same or not. If not, the expectation is $0$. If yes, we get the terms of the RHS (the coefficient is $\binom 42\times\sum_{1\leqslant i\lt j\leqslant n}1$).

The fourth sum is $n\mathbb EX_1^4$.